# Unit test ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate concepts. I have learnt association mappings from net and have executed all the association mappings with all possibilities like Jointable for OneToMany and OneToOne also in both unidirectional and bidirectional way and i managed to write unit test for all those except ManyToMany , OneToMany and OneToOne which have been written using @joinTable. As the third join table is created in database and as there is no mapping java file for that third jointable i am unable to test the contents of the data present in Third table.

Is there any way to test the contents of those tables which are created using @JoinTable annotation in ManyToMany or OneToMany or OneToOne. Well i guess its not possible as there is no mapping java class is there. but out of curiosity i am asking this question.

Comment: Use JDBC to get the contents of the table, or simply load the entities and test that the association is correctly populated. If it is, then the table join table is populated.

Comment: That would basically unittest you ORM, hibernate in this case. What you tend to do is to create a new instance of your model, persist it, load it and compare it with the original (hence a proper `equals` method is important). With this approach, you implicitly test your ORM. As for relations, you basically do the same, referencing the respective model instances.

Comment: ok thank you.... i did that both tables are populated correctly...